# Marketing cloud transactional email with no entry in subscriber list

Tags: marketing-cloud

We want to send transactional emails without making any entry in All subcriber list. It should behave just like SMTP integration. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

Sending an Email via Marketing Cloud **requires** creating a Subscriber somewhere in the platform, as it's mandatory with CAN-SPAM act for the Subscriber to have an option to opt-out of the messaging.

With Transactional Sends you simply have the option to either honor the opt-out status or not.

When creating a Triggered Send interaction in Marketing Cloud, then you can choose which List you will use for the Subscriber Management and you have the options to..

1. Add Subscribers to List
2. Update Subscribers on List

However if you choose NOT to select any of the List for the Triggered Send, then your Subscribers are added to a hidden system table that just isn't visible for you.

Read: [**Triggered Email Message Interaction**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_create_triggered_email_interaction.htm&type=5)

> Failing to select a list results in use of the Triggered Send Managed
>   List, a hidden system-defined List, to track status. Avoid this
>   scenario as the Triggered Send Managed List does not support all
>   triggered send-based functionality.

Comment: Please note too that you need to have a data extension associated with the TSD if you choose to not add to All Subs list. Another note is that you should make sure that the SubscriberKey you are passing does not have any spaces or similar 'hidden' chars as this can cause errors on your future sends, especially if they are later added to All Subs.

Comment: Also, this hidden list is added into the DataView `_Subscribers` and can be accessed via data extract inside the Subscribers file.

Comment: @Gortonington - so if we want someone to confirm their email address before they are added to our SF org and then Marketing Cloud, we would be able to send the confirmation email from MC but there would be a cleanup job required to delete from All Subs or the hidden list post-activation (we’d have two subscriber records at that point)?